# Can I use the row record as header for a table?

Tags: sql, database, row

Let say I have 2 table, rowName and realRecord

rowName has 2 column

1.Index______________2.FieldName

1____________________Name

2____________________Surname

3____________________Age

4____________________Gender

And realRecord column header will depend on what I have for field name in the previous table. For example in this case, realRecord will have Name, Surname, Age and Gender as header

I wish to do it as I may have to add additional column and I want to add to rowName table as it will be neater

Answer (score 1):

Assume your table rowName has following records:

```
Index  |  FieldName
-------------------
1      |  Name
2      |  SurName
3      |  Age
4      |  Gender
```

Your RealRecord has,

```
RecordID |  EmployeeID  |   FieldIndex  |  Value
1        |  E123        |   1           |  Nishanthi
2        |  E123        |   2           |  Grashia
```

and so on... If you want a new field say Nationality, You can perhaps add additional records as below:
**rowName :**

```
Index  |  FieldName
-------------------
5      |  Nationality
```

**RealRecord**

```
RecordID |  EmployeeID  |   FieldIndex  |  Value
100      |  E123        |   5           |  Indian
```

You can achieve this scenario easily if you have realRecord structure as in my answer (Multiple Rows instead of Multiple Headers as per your existing spec)